# Json.net serialization of own SynchronizedCollection

Tags: c#, json.net

I've written a very basic synchronized collection for using in a desktop app. Is there any way to do it better/easier than this? The collection needs to be serialized directly by json.net and obviously it needs to be synchonized.

Also i want to know if it is possible to cast to an unknown generic type to call the copy function generic without casting to an interface. i think this could be really slow on a large list and seems not neccessary.

```
public class SynchronizedCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
         return objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(SynchronizedCollection<>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        // make list type from SynchronizedCollection generic type
        var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
        // create instance of list type
        var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

        // populate json to our list!
        serializer.Populate(reader, list);

        // create new SynchronizedCollection from populated list, easy! <3 json <3 c#
        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, list);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        SynchronizedCollectionCopy collection = value as SynchronizedCollectionCopy;

        // get a copy of the list synchronously
        using (var waitTask = Task.Run<List<object>>(async () => { return await collection.Copy(); }))
        {
            // wait for synchronization.
            waitTask.Wait();

            // aaand serialize
            serializer.Serialize(writer, waitTask.Result);
        }            
    }
}

public interface SynchronizedCollectionCopy
{
    Task<List<object>> Copy();
}

public class SynchronizedCollection<T> : IDisposable, SynchronizedCollectionCopy
{
    private List<T> _storage;
    private SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public int Count { get { return _storage.Count; } }

    public SynchronizedCollection()
    {
        _storage = new List<T>();
    }
    public SynchronizedCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _storage = new List<T>(items);
    }

    public async Task Add(T item)
    {
        await _lock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            _storage.Add(item);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task Remove(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        await _lock.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            T item;
            while ((item = _storage.FirstOrDefault(predicate)) != null)
            {
                _storage.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task Perform(Action<List<T>> actionOnList)
    {
        await _lock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            actionOnList(_storage);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task<List<object>> Copy()
    {
        await _lock.WaitAsync();
        List<object> list = null;

        try
        {
            list = new List<object>(_storage.Cast<object>());
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _lock.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Given that your class does not implement `ICollection<T>` this is probably easiest.  2) Casting to an interface should take very little time, much less than any of the work done by Json.NET.  But multiple calls to `Activator.CreateInstance` might take some time.  Have you profiled it?  Relatedly, see https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/.  3) By returning a `List<object>` you box value types.  Consider returning a `T []` array typed as a `System.Array` and letting Json.NET infer the element type.  Also consider providing a non-async version of `Copy()` for convenience.

Comment: 4) In your `ReadJson()` you ignore the incoming `object value`.  You might want to check if it is non-null and can be cast to a `SynchronizedCollection<T>`, and if so, populate it and return it rather than populating and returning a new one.  5) Rather than allocating and populating a `List<T>` in two steps, just use [`serializer.Deserialize(reader, listType)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize_1.htm) in one step.  6) Since your code works this question might be better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thx for the advice! I totally forgot about codereview on SE.  For point 4 under which circumstance could the object value be set when ReadJson gets called?

Comment: I didnt express myself right the cast to the Interface is fast i know but casting the whole list to List<object> which i didnt even Need to know at WriteJson that might be slow.

Comment: *under which circumstance could the object value be set when ReadJson gets called?*  - For instance, when deserializing into an object with a get-only, preallocated collection, for instance `public class RootObject<T>
    {
        readonly ObservableCollection<T> collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        public ObservableCollection<T> Collection { get { return collection; } }
    }`

Comment: @dbc ah, ok i get the point. Thx for your help!